# Javascript button to open a VF page from Managed Package, on click asking me to login again

Tags: visualforce, javascript, managed-package, custom-button

I have a javascript button to redirect me to a VF page from managed package.
When i click on the button it is asking me to login to access that page.
How do i solve this?

Comment: Can you post the js script on the button? It is difficult to diagnose without. It may be that the button is trying to load a new instance therefore asking you to login.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Joe Hayes. I figured out the solution. It was because previously it was redirecting to the VF page by forming a url of different instance. Changed the code to redirect it to same instance by giving namespac__vfpagename. But answer also means the same. Thank you